# text alongside images that uses \caption and \label, universal placement code

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, cross-referencing, captions

Within my documents, I always need to place text and images along side each other. Sometimes the text is on the left other times on the right. I always need a `\caption` and `\label` which I need control where it is located around the image. I put together this code:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
Shows the progression of an industrial emerging technology. This process can be a few months to decades, depending upon the level of technology.
\end{minipage}

%
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    \captionof{figure}{Industrial emergence phase}  
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{foo.png}
    \label{img:g}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

It almost works, but the `\caption` is not correct. There must be a 'Universal' way of doing this as it appears everywhere. I don't want to use a wordwrap.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a *full* compilable code. What's not correct, exactly?

Comment: I don't understand the issue with `\label` here. As long as you are able to use a caption, `\label` should work

Comment: \caption expands to \textwidth (which in this case is the width of the minipage).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean when you say "the `\caption` is not correct". However on the assumption that you want the caption to be centered under the text and image then 3 `minipage` environments is an answer. As you haven't provided an MWE I won't either.

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    Text at the side
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    This is the illustration
  \end{minipage}
  \centering
  \captionof{figure}{This is the caption}% from the caption package
  \label{img:g}
\end{minipage}

The figure is number \ref{img:g}
```

Change the sizes and positions of the interior `minipage` environments to suit.